# Map, EvenQ, and the correct syntax

Tags: string-manipulation

Using `If` and `EvenQ` defines a pure function, which when applied to an integer, computes its square when the integer is even, and computes its cube when the integer is odd. Apply `Map` to the function over the following list: `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`

After mapping:

```
Map[f][{4, 27, 16, 125, 36, 343, 64}]
```

Output:

```
{f[4], f[27], f[16], f[125], f[36], f[343], f[64]}
```

I tried incorrectly that might be close to pseudocode and seek help how to implement the same the Wolfram way.

```
f[x_] := x^2 if EvenQ
f[x_] := x^3 if OddQ
```

My apology for not keeping with the syntax.

Comment: `f[x_] := If[EvenQ[x], x^2, x^3];`

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ - Since `EvenQ` returns `False` when `x` is not explicitly an integer; for a symbolic argument `f` would return the argument cubed. Consequently, the argument to `f` should be restricted to being numeric, i.e., `f[x_?NumericQ] := If[EvenQ[x], x^2, x^3]`. A symbolic argument would then return unevaluated.

Comment: Look up `Condition` if you want to pursue your pseudocode idea. (But you won't need `If` in that case.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Map[If[EvenQ[#], #^2, #^3] &, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]

(*  {4, 27, 16, 125, 36, 343, 64}  *)
```

Have fun!